# Using opengl32.DLL in 64 bit JRE?

Tags: java, opengl, jna

I was wondering this because from what I know, I've never seen a 64 bit opengl DLL stock on at least Windows no matter if it's 32 bit or 64 bit. So I'm stuck using what I got, which is the 32 bit opengl DLL. So is there any way I can still call it?

Comment: What does OpenGL ES 1.1 have to do with *Windows* OpenGL?

Comment: It's just the OpenGL version I'm using, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You can't use OpenGL ***ES*** 1.1 on Windows. That simply is not available. OpenGL32.dll only exposes *desktop* OpenGL; it doesn't expose any version of OpenGL ES. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL32.dll is always the DLL name, even for 64-bit Windows. It retains the same name, but it will be a 64-bit DLL if your application is built as a 64-bit application. So it's not loading the same DLL, just a DLL with the same name.